# Couldn't find any package whose name or description matched "beanstalkd"

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, beanstalkd

I am trying ton install beanstalkd on ubuntu 14.

I have tried using following commands

```
aptitude install -y beanstalkd

apt-get install beanstalkd
```

But I am getting following errors

> Couldn't find any package whose name or description matched
>   "beanstalkd" Couldn't find any package whose name or description
>   matched "beanstalkd" No packages will be installed, upgraded, or
>   removed. 0 packages upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 622
>   not upgraded. Need to get 0 B of archives. After unpacking 0 B will be
>   used.
>
> Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree        Reading
>   state information... Done E: Unable to locate package beanstalkd

Can anyone help me how to do that.

Comment: Possible aid: see https://askubuntu.com/a/1227917/80644